# How do I get the ID of a record with highest up-votes grouped by parent field?

Tags: mysql, database

The following is my table named nested-tree

[Database snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NWMQ.jpg)

I tried running this query:

```
SELECT id,max(upvotes),parent 
  FROM nested-tree 
 WHERE fid=1 
 GROUP BY parent
```

I get the highest upvotes grouped by parent field but I don't properly get which id has the highest upvotes.

The following is the table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `nested-tree` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ctime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `contents` varchar(1024) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `upvotes` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lft` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rgt` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

ALTER TABLE `nested-tree`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `fid` (`fid`);

INSERT INTO `nested-tree` (`id`, `fid`, `user_id`, `ctime`, `contents`, `upvotes`, `lft`, `rgt`, `parent`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1434, '2017-06-02 07:31:32', 'ELECTRONICS', 0, 1, 20, 0),
(2, 1, 1434, '2017-06-02 07:31:32', 'TELEVISIONS', 0, 2, 9, 1),
(3, 1, 1434, '2017-06-02 07:31:32', 'TUBE', 0, 3, 4, 2),
(4, 1, 1434, '2017-06-02 07:31:32', 'LCD', 9, 5, 6, 2),
(5, 1, 1434, '2017-06-02 07:31:32', 'PLASMA', 13, 7, 8, 2),
(6, 1, 1434, '2017-06-02 07:31:32', 'PORTABLE ELECTRONICS', 0, 10, 19, 1),
(7, 1, 1434, '2017-06-02 07:31:32', 'MP3 PLAYERS', 0, 11, 14, 10),
(8, 1, 1434, '2017-06-02 07:31:32', 'FLASH', 0, 12, 13, 11),
(9, 1, 1434, '2017-06-02 07:31:32', 'CD PLAYERS', 0, 15, 16, 10),
(10, 1, 1434, '2017-06-02 07:31:32', '2 WAY RADIOS', 4, 17, 18, 10);
```

Comment: Added a snapshot of the table, please help

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Check the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is asked endlessly on SO. Occasionally it is correctly answered, too. The topic even has its own chapter in the manual. Oh, and don't include '-' in a table/column identifier. That's just asking for trouble.

Anyway:

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN (SELECT parent, MAX(upvotes) upvotes FROM my_table WHERE fid = 1 GROUP BY parent) y
    ON y.parent = x.parent
   AND y.upvotes = x.upvotes;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. 
I'm new to sql, will remember about '-' thing.